# How to Install Anaconda Python

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda on a few Windows machines in the past, but now I'm unable to.

I go here: https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual

And click on the Windows 64 bit installer. Only Python 3.8 available, but that's fine.  I briefly see a small window stating the download is starting.
But then I get taken to this page: https://www.anaconda.com/access-experts-in-the-data-science-community where I look like I have to sign up.  Is this a new thing?

I don't see a download happening, and there's nothing in my download folder.

Do we have to register with Anaconda now before we can download and install?

Comment: I just tried it using Chrome on Windows 10 and it seems to work fine for me. A download started right before the "sign-up" window appeared.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks.  I've tried on 2 machines here, no luck.

Comment: What browser? Are you certain the downloads folder is where your browser downloads files to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, found the answer, leaving it here in case anyone else has this issue.

I put Net Nanny on all our home computers a few days ago.  And it's this that is stopping the download from starting.  I disabled it and it works.

Thanks for the help anyway.